# Split array and add to new array in while loop

Tags: c#

I have a flat file that I am reading in C# and then attempting to parse. I mean to store the account number in the flat file in an array.

```
 AccountNumber | AccountName | DateCreated 
 1             | Bob         | 1/1/2011    
 2             | Donna       | 3/2/2013    
 3             | Jake        | 2/21/2010   
 5             | Sally       | 4/2/2014
```

So far this is what my splitting looks like:

```
//List<string[]> myArrayList = new List<string[]>();
 using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\text\Accounts.txt"))
             {
                 string line;
                 while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     string[] parts = line.Split('|');
                     Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);
                     //myArrayList.Add(parts[0]);
                 }
             }
```

How do I store everything that's printed in parts[0] in it's own array outside of the while loop? I've tried doing a list add but I keep getting errors for invalid arguments. I commented out the bits that don't work.

Comment: Your `myArrayList` is the wrong data type. `parts[0]` will return a `string`, not a `string[]`.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't read all of the Text at once along with splitting the file..? you could even do one better by creating a class that is the same structure of the file and save the data into a List<Class> that you created ...

Comment: @krillgar I fixed my data type and now it works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code reads the contents of the file, splits the lines, stores it in a list and finally displays the first column in a RichTextBox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> myArrayList = new List<string[]>();
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\test\Accounts.txt");

        string line;
        while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split('|');
            //Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);
            myArrayList.Add(parts);
        }

        foreach (var account in myArrayList)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + account[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like MethodMan's suggestion:

```
// Class structure
public class Account
{
    public int AccountNumber;
    public string AccountName;
    public DateTime DateCreated;

    public Account(string[] info)
    {
        // This is all dependent that info passed in, is already valid data.  
        // Otherwise you need to validate it before assigning it
        AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(info[0]);
        AccountName = info[1];
        DateCrated = DateTime.Parse(info[2]);
    }
}
```

Your code using the class structure:

```
List<Account> myAccounts = new List<Account>();
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\text\Accounts.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split('|');
        myAccounts.Add(new Account(parts));
    }
}

// Do whatever you want after you have the list filled
```